# Statistics probability using variance and expected value

Tags: probability, statistics

An average customer buys an average of 3,4 plane tickets with variance being 2. 100 people are looking forward to buying a ticket. What is the probability that everyone gets a ticket when there are 350 tickets available?

I don't know what to use here. Should I perhaps use normal distribution or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You should indeed use the normal distribution via the Central Limit Theorem which applies here. For $i=1,2,\dots, 100$ denote with $X_i$ the tickets that the $i$-th customer buys, with $E[X_i]=3,4$ and $\mathrm{Var}(X_i)=2$. Thus, the following conditions apply

1. $X_1, X_2, \ldots X_{100}$ are independent identically distributed (iid) random variables, with
2. mean $μ=3,4$ and
3. variance $σ^2=2$.

We want to calculate the probability $$P(S_{100}<350)$$ where $S_{100}$ denotes the sum of the $X_i$'s, i.e $$S_{100}:=X_1+X_2+\ldots+X_{100}$$ By the Central Limit Theorem (CLT) the random variable $S_{100}$ follows the normal distribution with parameters $μ_{100}=100\cdot3,4$ and $σ^2_{100}=100\cdot2$ approximately. In symbols $$S_{100} \sim \mathrm N(μ_{100}=340, σ^2_{100}=200)$$ Therefore $$P(S_{100}<350)=P\left(\frac{S_{100}-μ_{100}}{σ_{100}}<\frac{350-340}{\sqrt{200}}\right)=P(Z<0.707)=\Phi(0,707)=0.76025$$